aThe name 'tabler' does not exist in the current context
I'm migrating a .NET 7 Blazor app to a .NET 8, and I am getting a compiler error in the App.razor file about this particular line:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tabler/icons-webfont@latest/tabler-icons.min.css">

The error is  The name 'tabler' does not exist in the current context
It's complaining specifically about the '@' symbol in front of tabler.  Is there a way to work around this?  Thank you!

In razor syntax @ is a symbol to start c# code. You coud escape @ by using @@
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@tabler/icons-webfont@latest/tabler-icons.min.css">
<i class="ti ti-home" style="font-size: 24px; color: red;"></i>

Test result

